# What is the best way to bundle MSIs for different platforms?

Tags: windows-installer, bundle, cpu-architecture

I have two MSI installers, for x86 and x64 architectures. I'd like to bundle them together into a unified installer than selects the correct installer based on the machine's architecture and launches it.

I've had some success with dotNetInstaller, but it just creates an extra exe file, the msi's must be included as separate files so this is not appropriate.

I can't believe this is such a rare task, but I haven't been able to find much else, can someone point me towards a good bundling/bootstrapping program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Embedding_other_installers), which is free, minimal, scriptable, and provides good compression.

My script is as follows:

```
!include x64.nsh

AutoCloseWindow true
SilentInstall silent
SetCompressor /SOLID lzma

Section
Initpluginsdir
${If} ${RunningX64}
  File "/oname=$pluginsdir\inst.msi" "64bit.msi"
${Else}
  File "/oname=$pluginsdir\inst.msi" "32bit.msi"
${EndIf}
ExecWait '"msiexec" /i "$pluginsdir\inst.msi"'
SectionEnd
```

This compiles to an installer that launches the correct MSI installer with no extra UI.

Answer (score 2):

[Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) has a feature called "[Convert EXE to MSI](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-convert-exe-to-msi.html)" which can be used to wrap your MSI packages too.

Another option from Advanced Installer is to simply add the two MSI packages as feature-based prerequisites in [Prerequisites page](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/prerequisites.html).

Comment: Is the Advanced Installer tool free? Is it possible to script it from the command line?

Comment: It has a free version, but it does not contain the above mentioned features. To accomplish what I described above you need at least a Professional edition.
It has a command line interface available in all editions, which you can use to build and edit the projects.

Comment: I ended up using NSIS, which is free and provided just what I need.